# C put crossword horizontal words to new array

Tags: c, arrays, crossword

I have a full filled crossword and i want to do a program to scan the horizontal words and put them into a new array the crossword is 20x20 array and the new array will be 40x20.
ex. If i find 3 horizontal words like: dog, cat, fish the 40x20 must look like
dog --> the first line
cat
fish
0
...
0 --> the 40th line
(Max words will be 40 because 40x20 = 40 lines)
one line per word... What i have  done so far is not so much.....

```
#include<stdio.h>
char cross[20][20]={
                {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
                {'*','T','Y','P','E','*','*','*','*','G','U','I','T','A','R','I','S','T','*','*'},
                {'*','E','*','*','V','A','I','N','*','A','*','*','*','V','*','*','T','*','I','*'},
                {'*','R','O','M','E','*','*','*','*','M','A','R','R','I','A','G','E','*','N','*'},
                {'*','R','*','*','N','O','O','D','L','E','*','O','*','A','*','*','A','N','T','*'},
                {'*','I','N','*','*','*','*','O','*','*','*','P','E','T','R','O','L','*','I','*'},
                {'*','F','*','C','*','C','U','T','*','L','I','E','*','I','*','A','T','O','M','*'},
                {'*','I','*','O','*','U','*','*','M','*','N','*','M','O','U','T','H','*','A','*'},
                {'*','E','N','V','E','L','O','P','E','*','F','*','I','N','*','H','*','A','T','*'},
                {'*','D','*','E','*','T','*','*','A','*','E','*','N','*','*','*','A','G','E','*'},
                {'*','*','A','R','T','*','I','N','T','E','R','I','O','R','*','A','*','O','*','*'},
                {'*','K','*','*','O','*','R','*','*','A','T','*','R','O','B','B','E','R','Y','*'},
                {'*','A','T','*','A','I','R','*','S','T','I','R','*','O','*','O','*','A','*','*'},
                {'*','N','O','*','S','*','I','T','*','*','L','*','S','M','I','L','E','*','S','*'},
                {'*','G','*','*','T','*','T','*','O','*','I','*','O','*','N','I','G','H','T','*'},
                {'*','A','C','E','*','M','A','N','D','A','T','O','R','Y','*','T','O','*','O','*'},
                {'*','R','*','N','Y','*','T','*','E','*','Y','*','T','*','*','I','*','*','P','*'},
                {'*','O','*','D','O','*','E','*','*','*','*','I','*','O','Z','O','N','E','*','*'},
                {'*','O','N','*','U','N','D','E','R','W','A','T','E','R','*','N','O','U','N','*'},
                {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'}
};
int main(){
    int i,j,a,b;
    char cross1[40][20];

    for(a=0;a<40;a++){
        for(b=0;b<20;b++){
            cross1[a][b]='0';
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<40;i++){
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            printf("%c ",cross1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            printf("%c ",cross[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0,a=0;i<20;i++){
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            if(cross[i][j]=='*'){}
            else{
                cross1[i][j]=cross[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Cross1:\n");
    for(i=0;i<40;i++){
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            printf("%c ",cross1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: LoL, yes how to do it -.- any help? How to scan horizontal and put the words in the new array one per line?

Comment: At the moment, you are only printing the same grid again and again. What do you have trouble with? Finding the words between the asterisks? Storing them in an extra array?

Comment: Yes i want to find the words HORIZONTAL and put them in an extra array ONE WORD per line! Please.. some help!

Comment: I dont care about the vertical words,i want to put only the horizontal words to a new array can you help?

Comment: @Sotnam96 You should be careful about the limit of 40 lines - what if a crossword has more? You mentioned that "40x20 = 40" - it's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine picking words from just one line! Can you do that? If yes, write the code and wrap it with a loop:

```
for (line = 0; line < 20; ++line)
{
    // cross[line] is just one line
}
```

If you don't know how to pick words from 1 line, here is an idea. Have a temporary variable "place where the words starts", initialized to -1. Scan the array; if you find a letter, remember where it is. If you find a non-letter, print the word and forget it. A horizontal word should have more than 1 letter in the horizontal direction - this is the way you can distinguish between horizontal and vertical words.

Something like this:

```
start_index = -1;
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    if (line[i] == '*')
    {
        if (start_index != -1 && i - start_index > 1)
            printf(...);
    }
    else
    {
        if (start_index == -1)
            start_index = i;
    }
}
```

If you use this code, you should modify it to account for words that terminate on the right margin.

Comment: He may also not want to include "words" with just a single letter.